# Anchor links open in new window if there's a query string and can this be prevented?

Tags: html, browser

I have a webpage with an address like `example.com` that contains links like `#page-link` and these work as expected: clicking the link jumps within the same page.

But then I have the same link on the same page, but with a query string: `example.com?key=value`. If I click on this link, it opens the url `example.com?key=value#page-link` in a new window and this isn't what I want.

I've seen this in several browsers, so I assume it's the correct behavior, but in my case I want the anchor link to jump to the named location in the same page.

What's going on here, and is there a way to get the behavior I want?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have the attribute 'target' set to '_blank' for the anchors?

Comment: There is no target set on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix it by inering the listener to the links `target` with the value `_self`, so the browser has to load the link in the same page as the user is.
Example:

```html
<a href="?key=keyValue#page-link" target="_self">Load example.com example</a>
```

or a simple example: `<a href="//example.com?key=keyValue#page-link" target="_self">Load example.com example</a>` where //example.com is the website you are trying to redirect the user to.
If the website where you want to redirect the user is the same as the location of the link then you can try the two examples above.
If not check if there is no scripts that interpretates the link a new page loading funtion.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that, while there was no target set for the link, there was a jQuery routine hooking the click event that, in certain cases, was overriding the default behavior and opening the clicked link in a new window. So, I was shooting myself in the foot here.